# first program to run after ssh connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, etc

I have a user 'test' and I had modified /etc/passwd file to run a certain script of my own (lets call it somescript.sh) whenever 'test' logs-in or does ssh.

I later changed the '/etc/passwd' file to run '/bin/bash' (the default program to run) whenever 'test' login-in or does ssh, but still whenever 'test' logs-in/ssh the previous script (somescript.sh) runs and not bash.

Not sure who to rectify this. Please help. Thanks

**EDIT**

`test:x:1001:1001:test,,,:/home/test:/home/admin/scripts/script.sh` ==> before

`script.sh` is a shell script that accepts users inputs in a loop, there is a option 'quit' on which I break from the loop and the script ends

`test:x:1001:1001:test,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash` ==> after

Comment: Did you use `usermod` for changing the login shell?

Comment: No, I did not. Do I have to use `usermod` command? I thought if just by changing /etc/passwd file should do the trick as before.

Comment: There can be all kinds of caching mechanisms inside the system that aren't updated when you edit the file directly. The `chsh` command mentioned below is even better.

Comment: chsh and usermod both did not help. Still facing the same issue

Comment: Have you verified that the change was also reflected in `/etc/passwd-` and that the [backup](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53128/difference-between-passwd-and-passwd-file) is not accidentally being used?

Comment: Yes the change also reflects in `/etc/passwd-`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what `somescript.sh` does there may be better ways to execute it upon login than by using `/etc/passwd`.  If possible you can login as test and use

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

that should set the login shell for test to bash.  Once that has been done there is some great information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97137/how-do-you-run-a-script-on-login-in-nix) about the different scripts that run when the bash shell starts, the order they run in, etc.  Once you know the appropriate file you can add the line

```
source /path/to/somescript.sh
```

to that file and it will run every time the user logs in.

Comment: chsh did not help. Still facing the same problem.

Comment: is there any chance you can post an example of `/etc/passwd` with the changes that were made before and after?  obviously not the exact `/etc/passwd` you are using, but if you could boot a live OS image or clean/disposable VM and try to recreate the issue in a clean environment more details and/or step by step snapshots of the relevant files would be useful.  On a somewhat related note have you tried deleting and recreating the test user?

Comment: I have edited the question with before and after changes of /etc/passwd. I have not tried deleting and re-creating test user.

Comment: The link to another question really helped. Thanks